# navigation.dispatch SET_PARAMS was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have 3 screens and I just want the last screen to modify the previous screen's params. Navigable like this:

`Home` -> `Feature` -> `Settings`

`Home` -> `Feature` has a `data` param, something like `navigation.navigate("FeatureScreen", { data: data })`.

`Feature` -> `Settings` is pretty straightforward, something like `navigation.navigate("SettingScreen")`.

`Settings` screen itself is a standalone screen and it pulls some data and modify it, and now I want to update the `data` param in `Feature` screen via `Settings`'s button action (i.e. button press will set/pass the `data` data back to previous screen).

This is a working example in `Settings` screen:

```
navigation.setOptions({
            headerLeft: () => (
                <Button
                    title="< Back"
                    onPress={() => {
                        // Pass and merge params back to home screen
                        navigation.navigate({
                            name: "FeatureScreen",
                            params: { data: newFullListOfData },
                            merge: true,
                        });
                    }}
                />
            )
```

It works *but* unfortunately, the downside is that it modifies the `Back` button which I am not keen.

I came across `setParams`, which allows me to call `navigation.dispatch` with type `SET_PARAMS` and no need to modify my `Back` button. This is the code I have now in `Settings` screen save button:

```
        const setParamsAction = CommonActions.setParams({
            data: newFullListOfData
        });

        navigation.dispatch(state => {
            const route = state.routes.find(route => route.name == "FeatureScreen")
            return ({ ...setParamsAction, target: route?.key })
        });
```

Which seems to be great BUT I am getting that dreaded red "The action 'SET_PARAMS' with payload {"params":my-data-here} was not handled by any navigator."

Given that I have provided the `target` route key, any idea why it is still not working?
I printed out the data for `state` and `route` and it seems to be populated correctly with the data.

I am using React Navigation 6.x, functional components, and testing on iOS:

```
"@react-navigation/native": "6.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.12",
```

Any help to try and resolve this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `source` property to set params for a particular route.

```
navigation.dispatch((state) => {
  return {
    ...CommonActions.setParams({ ... }),
    source: state.routes.find(r => r.name == '?').key
  };
});
```

See [setParams](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#setparams) for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working. I thought it was supposed to be `target` as the destination that we want to change params for, as `source` in itself didn't made sense at all to me. Don't think I came across an example like this before. Nonetheless thank you.